# What is causing this System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Error. Issue with my SqlDataAdapter

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, sqldataadapter

I am not sure why I am getting this error. The description of my problem is below the code. I have excluded some of the Select Cases and fields in the below code to keep it as short as possible.

```
 Private Sub SetClassGrid(ByVal ClassCategory As String)
    Dim connectionString As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("theDataBase").ConnectionString
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim sqlCommand As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

    sqlCommand.Append("SELECT Name, City, State FROM Classes$ WHERE (ClassesCategoryID = ")

    Select Case ClassCategory
        Case "Art"
            sqlCommand.Append("1)")
        Case "Drama"
            sqlCommand.Append("2)")
        Case "Aquarium"
             sqlCommand.Append("2)")         
    End Select

    Dim cmd As String = sqlCommand.ToString()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    Try
        con.Open()
        da.Fill(ds, "Classes$")

    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try

    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Classes$")
    GridView1.DataBind()


End Sub
```

For the Select Case- when *ClassCategory* = "Art" it works fine; however when *ClassCategory* equals anything else, I get an error.

Also for the Select Case- if the case is "Art" and if I change *sqlCommand* from ="1)" to ="2)" it works as intended.

So the issues are that the above code only works for the first Case.
[image]

Comment: I am getting this exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='.  At da.Fill(ds, "Classes$")

Comment: What does the debugger show? What's the value of `sqlCommand` when the error occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does the debugger show? What's the value of `sqlCommand` when the error occurs?

Just to make sure the query is valid anyway, add a default behavior for your `select case`:

```
Select Case ClassCategory
    Case "Art"
        sqlCommand.Append("1)")
    Case "Drama"
        sqlCommand.Append("2)")
    Case "Aquarium"
        sqlCommand.Append("2)")
    Case Else
        sqlCommand.Append("-1)")
End Select
```

Even better, parameterize your query:

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name, City, State FROM Classes$ WHERE " + 
                                    "ClassesCategoryID = @Id", connection);

// Add the parameters for the SelectCommand.
command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);

adapter.SelectCommand = command;
```

And fill the parameter in your `select case`:

```
Select Case ClassCategory
    Case "Art"
        command.Parameters["@Id"].Value = 1;
    Case "Drama"
        command.Parameters["@Id"].Value = 2;
    Case "Aquarium"
        command.Parameters["@Id"].Value = 2;
    Case Else
        command.Parameters["@Id"].Value = -1;
End Select
```

Comment: Linus, the ID is added in the Select Case with the string builder variable 'sqlCommand'

Comment: But there is no default behavior in case `ClassCategory` does not match any predefined `Case`.

Comment: I have Case Else, I just excluded here because ClassCategory always executes the correct case, I just have an error with the sql somewhere. The query executes correctly on Case "Art", but nothing else. I changed sqlCommand = "2)" for Case "Art", and the query returned the correct data for the ClassCategoryID of 2 -which is "Drama."

Comment: Sure you postet the original code? Because I can't see an error. Just one thing: You do not need the brackets.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! As you can see, I was using command as a string. The reason for this was because, when I declared da As New SqlDataAdapter(), I was passing it the arguments 'command' and 'con.' Doing so- da had an error. Then from your code, I realized that I should be passing con to command, not da.

Answer (score 0):

consider adding break; ? try to go step by step, and right before your code executes the query, try to copy the query sql and execute it in the server manually, it looks like the query is messed up

Comment: VB Select Cases don't have breaks (that I am aware of). Yea, the query being messed up was my first thought. I have stepped through the code line by line, and the select command is as it should be, so I am lost from here.

Comment: Right, i appologize...i was reading VB but in my head it was a switch statement. the last thing i sugest is to check your connection string !

Comment: It was a connection issue, but not the string. I was passing the connection string to the SqlDataAdapter, opposed to my SqlCommand. Thank you for your responses.